# Check and calculate the evening working hour

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm writing a method that take the begin hour and end hour as parameters. This method will check and return the evening working hour (from `18:00` to `6:00`).

My solution is simply run a loop from begin to end, if begin is equal or greater than `18:00`, the counter will be incremented by one:

```
public static float CheckIfEveningWork(DateTime begin, DateTime end) {
    float eveningWorkDuration = 0;

    if (begin.getHourOfDay() > end.getHourOfDay()) {
        end = end.plusHours(24);
        for (float a=begin.getHourOfDay(); a<= end.getHourOfDay();a++) {
            if ((a>=18)||(a<=6)) {
                eveningWorkDuration++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (float a=begin.getHourOfDay(); a<= end.getHourOfDay();a++) {
            if ((a>=18)||(a<=6)) {
                eveningWorkDuration++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(end.getHourOfDay());
    return eveningWorkDuration;
}
```

When I test this method with

```
begin = 17:00
end = 2:00
```

It returned `0`. But when I tried:

```
begin = 17:00
end = 20:00
```

It returned `3`.

What I'm doing wrong here with the solution?

Comment: `3` sounds right, the hours are `18:00`, `19:00` and `20:00`

Comment: What is going on with this code : `for (float a=begin.getHourOfDay(); a<= end.getHourOfDay();a++) {
            if ((a>=18)||(a<=6)) {`   ???

Comment: if this is joda time please tag as such

Comment: added joda. That if-statement will check if a is inside the evening working hour (18:00-6:00)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, it's the 0 value you are concerned with, true? The conditions of the for-statement are not met: `a = begin.getHourOfDay()`, which is 17 here. But the condition of  `a <= end.getHourOfDay()` is false, and the for loop exits, leaving you with the result 0.

You have to think about the corner cases here a little more carefully.

To expand on that, if begin.getHourOfDay() > end.getHourOfDay(), then you have to iterate from begin.getHourOfDay() to 23 and 0 to end.getHourOfDay().

Try this instead:

```
public static float CheckIfEveningWork(DateTime begin, DateTime end) {
    float eveningWorkDuration = 0;
    float beginHour = begin.getHourOfDay();
    float endHour = end.getHourOfDay();

    if (beginHour < endHour) {
        for (float a=beginHour; a<= endHour; a++) {
            if ((a>=18)||(a<=6)) {
                eveningWorkDuration++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        endHour = endHour + 24;
        for (float a=beginHour; a<= endHour; a++) {
            if ((a>=18)||(a<=6)) {
                eveningWorkDuration++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(end.getHourOfDay());
    return eveningWorkDuration;
}
```

Comment: but I got the first if-statement to check if begin.getHourOfDay() < end.getHourOfDay(). If it returned true, end would have value 26 in my first example. After that, the for-loop started

Comment: Ok, but for your first example (17:00, 02:00), this condition is false, not true.

Comment: Based on the logic, the end.plusHours() is in the wrong spot... also, I don't know the joda time library, but my guess is that end.plusHours(24) is like adding one day... it's not going to change the hour of the day, so this isn't having the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I dont think so, because I did the same if-statement thing when I get the hours between begin and end. It worked pretty well.

Comment: Based on [Jodatime documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) the internal representation of the DateTime object is milliseconds from the Java epoch.  So the getHourOfDay() method is going to operate on this value and return a value in the range 0 to 23, indicating the hour of the day that the DateTime value represents.

Comment: then it is strange, because when I use the jodatime method Hours.hoursBetween(begin, end).getHours(), I use the same if-statement to check if (begin<end). Btw, can you help me with some hints to fix this ? I tried various ways but nothing worked